# WP Nav menu modify the urls with language code

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, multilingual

Using `wp_nav_menu()` ,How can i modify the urls of generated links to add the language code at end of each URL Like i have the url `http://www.example.com/` but i have to append the language parameter at the end ,So the url would be `http://www.example.com/?lang=$language`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the behaviour of `wp_nav_menu` with the `wp_get_nav_menu_items`-filter. Here's a somewhat complete example:

```
class ModifyLinkFilter {
    protected $_prio = 10;
    protected $_args;

    public function __construct($addargs = array(), $prio = 10) {
        $this->_args = $addargs;
        $this->_prio = $prio;

        if(!empty($addargs)) {
            $this->register();
        }
    }

    public function register() {
        add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items',
            array($this, 'on_nav_items'), $this->_prio, 3);
    }

    public function unregister() {
        remove_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items',
            array($this, 'on_nav_items'), $this->_prio, 3);
    }

    public function on_nav_items($items, $menu, $args) {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if(!empty($item->url)) {
                $item->url = self::modifyUrlSimple($item->url, $this->_args);
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }

    public static function modifyUrlSimple($url, $query) {
        $url .= strchr($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&';
        $url .= http_build_query($query);
        return $url;
    }
}


// You can use the class like that
$language = "de";
$args = array('lang' => $language, 'foo' => 'bar');
$linkfilter = new ModifyLinkFilter($args); 
wp_nav_menu();
$linkfilter->unregister();
```

This modifies every item in the navigation menu. So if you have an external link, it will be changed as well.

Plus, modifying the URL is not as easy as it seems. The URL of an item can be `/blabla?myvalue=5#anchor` which would look like `/blabla?myvalue=5#anchor&lang=de&foo=bar` after the modification.